# Animate Popup before closing

Tags: c#, animation, popup, windows-runtime

I'm making a program for Windows 8 in WinRT and I'm having some trouble with the [Popup-class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup%28v=win.10%29.aspx).

The content in the popup has a fancy intro-animation when it is opened. I'd like to animate the content in the popup right before it closes, but haven't found out how.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: This is an example for what I'm trying to do. The Closed-eventhandler is obviously too late for doing anything before it closes. But you get the point.

```
    Popup popup = new Popup();

    SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    Ellipse ell = new Ellipse() { Fill = brush, Width = 300, Height = 300 };
    popup.Child = ell;

    popup.Opened += (sender, e) =>
    {
        ColorAnimation anim = new ColorAnimation() { To = Colors.Blue };
        Storyboard.SetTarget(anim, brush);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, "Color");

        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Children.Add(anim);

        sb.Begin();
    };
    popup.Closed += (sender, e) =>
    {
        ColorAnimation anim = new ColorAnimation() { To = Colors.Green };
        Storyboard.SetTarget(anim, brush);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, "Color");

        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Children.Add(anim);

        sb.Begin();
    };

    popup.IsOpen = true;
```

Comment: Can you provide some source code demonstrating your popup?

Comment: See the question, I've added an example.

Comment: Any chance on using a normal [Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing.aspx) instead of a PopUp? The Window class provides an event for Closing.

Comment: No. I'll solve it by making my own class.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the popup has only 2 visibility states (`isopen =true/false`). when `IsOpen` is set to false (i.e. closed) the popup's visibility is set to Collapsed and the animation is not played. What I would suggest is:

The popup obviously has a close button to close it, right? So in that close button's click event, start the animation. Then listen to the completed event on the storyboard and set the `popup.IsOpen=false` there

```
sb.Completed += SomeEventHandler
```